# How do I serialize and XML SOAP response without access to the file system?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

Currently, I am serializing the response from my SOAP request to an XML file on the local disk. Users can view the contents of the XML at any time after they run the initial request, so I need to store the XML somewhere. The application I am building is going to run on Azure Web Apps and, from what I gathered, I cannot write to the disk on those servers. So the next best thing is to make a simple table in my DB and store the serialized XML. My problem is, I cannot serialize the XML using `System.XML.XmlSerializer.Serialize` because that method requires a StreamWriter, and without access to the file system, I cannot initialize `System.IO.StreamWriter`.

My serialization method looks like this:

```
/* Simplified SOAP request / response */
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
SoapResponse response = client.GetReport(soapRequest); //soapRequest = valid soap envelope

StreamWriter stWriter = null;            
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
string filePath = @"C:\ReportXml\reportName.xml"
xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());                                

stWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, response);
```

This won't work on Azure. Is there some kind of work around? Some way to serialize the XML without writing it to disk?

Comment: Just serialize it to a MemoryStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Simplified SOAP request / response */
SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
SoapResponse response = client.GetReport(soapRequest); //soapRequest = valid soap envelope

StreamWriter stWriter = null;            
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
var stream = new MemoryStream();
xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());                                

stWriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stWriter, response);
```

Comment: I'll try this out. Exactly what I was hoping I could do. Thx.

Comment: FYI anyone else using this solution. You must set `stream.Position = 0` before you can use `System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(stream)`